# sequelize returns twice the same row but with Capital case the 2nd

Tags: sequelize.js

for the following model

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Execution = sequelize.define('Execution', {
    uuid4 : DataTypes.STRING,
    componentId : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    isComplete : DataTypes.BOOLEAN    
  }, {});
  Execution.associate = function(models) {
    Execution.belongsTo(models.Component, {foreignKey: 'componentId', as: 'component'})
  };
  return Execution;
};
```

when creating a new "Execution" I get the following result :

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "uuid4": "d520ce1c-e240-4cdf-a584-70c78ef626a7",
    "componentId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2019-08-30T17:55:45.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-08-30T17:55:45.000Z",
    "ComponentId": 1
  }
]
```

Why the componentId appears twice? once with a capital "C"?. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ComponentId` is not generated by sequlize by default so it must be
>   typing issue somewhere in your code, if it was generated by sequlize
>   then it should look like `componentId`.

So it looks like typing issue, you might have defined the association for `Component` like this :

```
Component.hasMany(Execution, { foreignKey: 'ComponentId' }); // <--- HERE
OR
Component.hasOne(Execution, { foreignKey: 'ComponentId' }); // <--- HERE
```

**Just change `ComponentId` to `componentId`.**

Comment: in fact I wasn't defining the foreign key :
Execution.belongsTo(models.Component, {as: 'component'})
but adding it did the trick 
    Execution.belongsTo(models.Component, {foreignKey: 'componentId', as: 'component'})